# Use coordinator layout to create horizontally scrollable toolbar section headers that scroll to position in recyclerview [Android]

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-motionlayout, android-scrollable-tabs, android-scrolling

I want to create a complex layout that will contain a toolbar with tabs that will scroll to a category in a list; and that will also respond to the scroll events of the list; so when the users scrolls to a new section the tabs will horizontally scroll to the correct tab.

We are currently achieving this using a motion layout (for an unrelated image expansion scroll behaviour that takes place above the tabs and scroll listeners.

I think we are better off with a coordinator layout; so we have one component we are interacting with.

Is this possible?  Does anyone know of any samples or repos that you could point me to?